# Excel VBA Copy and paste "empty table"

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I'm using a code where I copy the data located under a table (so without keeping the headers) and I paste it into another table.

My issue is that when I have no data underneath the table, the table actually copies and pastes the headers into the other table.

The reason why I have an empty table with only headers is that it's a result of the filter, ie the filter has no results.

Anyways, the code looks like this

```
Sub Macro36()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

    'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
    Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column 1
    lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    '2 Find first bnak row in the destination range based in column A
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    '3. Copy & Paste Data
    
    wsCopy.Range("A2:H" & lCopyLastRow).Copy wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)

End Sub
```

My guess is that the reason isn't working is because the code is looking for a table that starts in column A, however, failing to do so it copies the headers as it registers this as the last row of the table.

In order to rectify this I have changed the wsCopy line so that it only looks for data from cell A2, however, I get an error on this section.

```
Sub Macro36()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

    'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
    Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Sheet 1")
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet 2")
    
    '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column 1
    lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.count, "A2:A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    '2 Find first bnak row in the destination range based in column A
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    '3. Copy & Paste Data
    
    wsCopy.Range("A2:H" & lCopyLastRow).Copy wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)

End Sub
```

Any ideas on what I could do to change things?

Thanks,

Comment: `Cells(wsCopy.Rows.count, "A2:A")` you can't do that. The second parameter is a column. A quick cheat is just to stick with A then +1?

Comment: Hi, okay so would I write the code like so '''Cells(wsCopy.Rows.count, "A"+1)''' ?

Comment: `lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row+1`